# How to get Data of a clicked Material Card into an Dialog in Angular2/4?

Tags: angular, material-design

I have an *ngFor loop that displays all the material cards(MatCard or mdCard if you are using older version) on the screen. And When I click on any MatCard a dialog opens. I want to insert the data of Material Cards into the Dialog.

This is my buyComponent.html

```
<div *ngIf="allItems" class="layout-row" >
<mat-card *ngFor="let item of allItems" class="flex-lg-20" (click)="OnMatCardClickEvent($event)">

  <mat-card-header class="flex-lg-20">
    <h2>{{item.itemName}}</h2>
    <br>
  </mat-card-header>
  <mat-card-content class="flex-lg-20">
    <h2>   </h2>
    <br>{{item.itemImageUrl}}
  </mat-card-content>

  <mat-card-content align="bottom" class="flex-lg-20">
    <div>Rs. {{item.itemPrice}}</div>

  </mat-card-content>
</mat-card><br><br><br>
```

This is my BuyComponent.ts

```
@Component({
selector: 'app-buy',templateUrl: './buy.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./buy.component.css']
})
export class BuyComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private sellItemService: SellItemService,

              private dialog:MatDialog) {
  }

  areThereItems: boolean = false;
  allItems: DialogItem[] = [];



  ngOnInit() {
    this.showAllItemDialogs();
  }

  OnMatCardClickEvent(){
    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ItemDialogComponent, {
      height: '400px',
      width: '600px'
    });
  }
```

This is my ItemDialog.html

```
    <div class="col-md-12">
  <br>
  <div>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>{{itemName}}</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label >{{itemImageUrl}}</label>
        </td>
      </tr>

    </table>
    <button type="submit" (click)="viewDetails()">View Details</button>
    <br>
    <label></label>
  </div>
</div>
```

ItemDialog.component.ts

```
 export class ItemDialogComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() item:any;

  constructor(sellItemService: SellItemService,@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) {
  }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

So I want to use itemName and other Item Data in the dialog which opens when I click on Material Card.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this code.

html - instead of passing `$event`, pass the object of item

```
<div *ngIf="allItems" class="layout-row" >
<mat-card *ngFor="let item of allItems" class="flex-lg-20" (click)="OnMatCardClickEvent(item)">

  <mat-card-header class="flex-lg-20">
    <h2>{{item.itemName}}</h2>
    <br>
  </mat-card-header>
  <mat-card-content class="flex-lg-20">
    <h2>   </h2>
    <br>{{item.itemImageUrl}}
  </mat-card-content>

  <mat-card-content align="bottom" class="flex-lg-20">
    <div>Rs. {{item.itemPrice}}</div>

  </mat-card-content>
</mat-card><br><br><br>
```

BuyComponent.ts

```
@Component({
selector: 'app-buy',templateUrl: './buy.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./buy.component.css']
})
export class BuyComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private sellItemService: SellItemService,

              private dialog:MatDialog) {
  }

  areThereItems: boolean = false;
  allItems: DialogItem[] = [];



  ngOnInit() {
    this.showAllItemDialogs();
  }
//function with param item object
  OnMatCardClickEvent(item:any){
    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ItemDialogComponent, {
      height: '400px',
      width: '600px'
    });

    dialogRef.componentInstance.itemName = item.itemName;
 dialogRef.componentInstance.itemImageUrl = item.itemImageUrl;
  }
```

ItemDialog.component.ts

```
     export class ItemDialogComponent implements OnInit {
      @Input() item:any;

     public itemName: string;
public itemImageUrl: string;

      constructor(sellItemService: SellItemService,@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) {
      }
      ngOnInit() {
      }
    }
```